# Git pull release from one repository to another

Tags: git, azure, pull, git-remote

I cloned a project X from Github locally and made some little changes , then i created my own repository and pushed my local project to it (using Azure DevOps) .

Now there is a new feature in project X , which i want to pull it to my Azure repository .

Does anyone have an idea? currently i don't have any relation between repo X and my Azure repo , and i think i should use git remote but i don't know how exactly

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Why don't you just pull from project X, then push that feature, presumably a feature branch to your Azure repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have something like, `origin` is set to track project X, `azure` is set to track your own repo, and `master` is your local copy of project X master, `little-change` is with your changes. Then step-by-step would be

1. switch to the master branch to get the new feature update from project X

   ```
   git checkout master
   git pull origin master
   ```
2. merge the new feature with your own changes

   ```
   git checkout little-change
   git pull azure little-change  # probably just git pull is sufficient
   git merge master              # fix conflict if there is any
   ```
3. push the new stuff to your own repo

   ```
   git push azure little-change
   ```

you can check your remote repo name and urls using `git remote -v`. Since you already cloned from project X and pushed to your own repo. Those should already be tracked in your local repo.